# Split key: value; pairs and exclude whitespace in matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, removing-whitespace

Let's say we've a string like this: `'  key1  :  value1  ;  key2  :  value2 value3  '` and we want to convert it into a javasript-`object`. We can match aything that is not a delimiter (`:;`) and capture these matches. Great, got this job done with a simple regular expression:

```
/([^:]+):?([^;]+);?/g
```

Problem with my current `RegExp` is, that it also include whitespace in the results. So the string above will result in something like this:

```
{
  "  key1  ": "  value1  ",
  "  key2  ": "  value2 value3  "
}
```

Not really what we want... So I've changed the `RegExp` to this:

```
/\s*([^:]+)\s*:?\s*([^;]+);?\s*/g
```

Arr, damn! The character-set `[^:]+` matches anything that is not a colon (so also *whitespace*). What will result in something like this:

```
{
  "key1  ": "value1  ",
  "key2  ": "value2 value3  "
}
```

Any idea how we can capture only the `key`s / `value`s, without including whitespace in the match. So that our result looks like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2 value3"
}
```

---

By the way, this is how the full parsing-function looks like:

```
var parseAttributes = function (attribute) {
  var REGEX_SPLIT_PAIRS = /;?([^:]+):?([^;]+);?/g;
  var attributes = {};
  var match;

  while (match = REGEX_SPLIT_PAIRS.exec(pairs)) {
    attributes[match[1]] = match[2];
  }

  return attributes;
};
```

**Edit**

Another way is doing it with splitting the *attribute*-string down into the pair-chunks. However, I think about a pure RegExp-solution, without `trim`:

```
var parseAttributes = function (attribute) {
  var attributes = {};

  attribute.split(';').forEach(function (pair) {
    var pairs = pair.split(':');
    if (pairs && pairs[0] && pairs[1]) {
      attributes[pairs[0].trim()] = pairs[1].trim();
    }
  });

  return attributes;
};
```

Comment: can I ask why you're not serializing the key/values using something more standardized, like JSON?

Comment: @naomik I think it looks a bit hacky, if we use something like `JSON.parse` on a none JSON-formatted string. At the first we've to wrap the string with curly braces and replace semicolons with commas (except the last one, this sould be removed). Apart from the fact, that this will be really slow. `JSON.parse` has not a so great browser-support as a simple `RegExp`-solution ;)

Comment: I never implied you should use `JSON.parse` on a non-JSON-formatted string, nor did I imply you should wrap your string with braces to hack it. `JSON.parse` has very wide browser support as well; and if you need to support a dinosaur browser, there's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Anyway, good luck.

Comment: [Regular Expressions: Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/); maybe see the bit about "Regular expressions are not Parsers."

Comment: @naomik Ah, ok I've misunderstood your question, sorry! I don't have any option, to change the format of the key/value-string, sadly... It is already in use by some templates in our project, the team would not be glad about a change :P Big thanks for the article you linked, looks  really interesting :-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to capture Key,Value pair separately

```
\s*(\S+)\s*:\s*([^;\s]*(?:\s*\w+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iK4xT3/1)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, however this will end up in `{key1: "value1", ;: "key2", :: "value2", value: "3"}` sadly not what I expect ;)

Comment: Damn, now it doesn't work without whitespace `key1:value1;key2:value2 value3;` => `{key1:value1;key2: "value2 value3"}`

Comment: but in the demo there is no spaces present before and after the value.

Comment: Nope it doesn't http://regex101.com/r/iK4xT3/2, here's a fiddle too: http://fiddle.jshell.net/akk2E/

Comment: Rarr, I love you :-* If I could, I would upvote again ;)

Comment: Yeah, for all my test-cases :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you guarantee that every entry will match the model "  key : value ;", that every entry will have a ":" and a ";" delimiter? If so, this may work:

```
/\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*([^;]+?)\s*;/g
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll take a look, could maybe possible. +1

Answer (score 0):

/\s*([^:]+)\s*:?\s*([^;]+);?\s*/g matches whitespace because the first match is greedy; to stop this just add a ? to the match.
I think that /\s*([^:]+?)\s*:?\s*([^;]+?)\s*;?\s*/g will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work but,
did you tried?  /[a-z0-9]+/g